# Change selected layer style in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, select, openlayers, layer

I need to change the style so that when I select a polygon from my layer it doesn't have the blue line as it is in this image. Does anyone know where I make this change with Openlayers?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the `Select` interaction - it has a `style` parameter as described in the docs:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select-Select.html

There is also an example for this:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-features.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm using ol.interaction.Select. Managed to change the style. The select is working with a simple click and shows a popup ol.Overlay.PopupFeature with the information of the selected feature. However, I would like that when I close the Popup, it executes a deselect event. It's possible? So that the style returns to the previous one.

Comment: I achieved. In Popup's onclose event: `select_interaction.getFeatures().clear();`